# How to install LXQt DE in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, desktop-environments, lxqt

I heard there is a new (Lightweight) Desktop environment available named as LXQt for Ubuntu and I would like to know how can I install it on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I installed lubuntu on top of ubuntu and got many interfaces including lxqt.  You need to go to the login screen to change the desktop (s) you installed.  In any case it changed my startup animation and it does not make things leaner.  The memory was the same about 500 mb.   Lubuntu fresh install is less than half.  They calm 100mb but i show 200mb and change on a full install.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To install LXQt in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS open your terminal and paste these commands one by one.

```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lubuntu-dev/lubuntu-daily 
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gilir/q-project
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install lxqt-metapackage lxqt-panel openbox
```

that will install LXQt in your Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

FYI: Currently there are many bugs. So don't try if having a stable and reliable system is a requirement for you.

Comment: You said " don't try if you are a Ubuntu user with some purpose" then which purposes you are talking about by means of "some purpose"?

Comment: @Pandya if you are a developer or serious worker.

Comment: don't you need to install openbox too for lxqt to work plus other packages? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6oDvcBNmtAM

Comment: @Fischer soon they are going to take care of it, as I mentioned here a daily PPA

Comment: so they are going to include openbox in the package or will they develop their own packages?

Comment: they will make it as one of the needy, so it will install automatically soon.

Comment: @BOSEDK THIS IS UBUNTU  https://www.google.co.in/search?q=LXQt+install+in+Ubuntu&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-beta&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=ErFxU9DoM6bM8geo3oDADg

Comment: @BOSEDK , we have plenty of sources. All are same. I dont care downvote. give me a bunch if you want. my main theme simple my friend , helping.

Comment: @DKBose I don't see anything that copy/pasted, if the command list is the same - it is because the process is the same and is common knowledge, http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/tag/lxde/ , http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2220270&page=9 , http://www.gaggl.com/2014/06/ubuntu-14-04-amazon-ec2-cloud-desktop-using-lxqt/ , http://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=36742 , http://www.maketecheasier.com/test-lxqt-ubuntu/ , http://pastebin.com/EyzHBL79 , http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-lxqt-on-ubuntu-14-04-and-ubuntu-13-10/

Comment: http://oldpapyrus.wordpress.com/2014/05/18/install-lxqt-on-ubuntu-14-04/ , http://nixspy.com/latestnews/lxqt-0-7-lxde-qt-released-install-ubuntu/ , http://linuxg.net/ubuntu-14-10-alpha-1-has-been-released-in-the-traditional-flavors/ , http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/05/generation-lightweight-de-lxqt-0-7-0/ , http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JihWRknh9Kw , @DKBose shall I go on? there are endless number of links saying the same thing, and your link isn't even on the first page of google of my search, your accusation is invalid, and downvote unwarranted.

Answer (score 3):

As previously stated, if you want to install lxqt on top of openbox you can:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lubuntu-dev/lubuntu-daily  
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gilir/q-project  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install openbox obconf
sudo apt-get install lxqt-metapackage lxqt-panel
```

If you're trying to install it as the only desktop on a given thing you can use `openbox`, `kwin`, or whatever other WM underneath the lxqt libraries/decorators.  I used `kwin` because I like a composited desktop without other bloat.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lubuntu-dev/lubuntu-daily  
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gilir/q-project  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install kdebase-runtime kdebase-workspace lightdm kubuntu-default-settings
sudo apt-get install lxqt-metapackage lxqt-panel
```

And change the logging in to option on lightdm from KDE to LXQT.

It looks pretty neat and clean this way.  I'll still have to go in and rip out some of the KDE icons/settings managers if I want it to look like an LXQT ONLY desktop with compositing, but it sure was easy to get it set up this way.

Note: I started with a server install as my minimal base. and it weighs in at about 3.6Gb installed, but lacks applications.

Answer (score 2):

[LXQt 0.7.0 DE in ubuntu 14.04](http://ubuntuportal.com/2014/05/how-to-install-lxqt-0-7-0-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr.html) include video and screenshot